# In the HTML5 canvas, is there a way to rotate images in different angles?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, rotation

Currently there are are two images I would like to rotate on the canvas, I tried save and restore but didn't work

```
        function SetCanvas()
       {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('pic1');

        if(canvas.getContext)
        {
             var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          //    ctx.save();
              ctx.rotate(0.5);
             var image = new Image();
              image.src ='ME.JPG';
              image.onload = function(){

                  ctx.drawImage(image, 90,0,200,100);

              };
        }
            //ctx.restore();
            var canvas2 = document.getElementById("pic2");
            var image2 = new Image();
            image2.src = 'ME2.JPG';
            if(canvas2.getContext)
            {
                    image2.onload = function(){
                            ctx2=canvas2.getContext('2d');
                            ctx2.drawImage(image2, 0,0,200,100); 
                    };
            }


        }

          <ul id="picsCanvas" style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap; list-style-type:none;">
               <li style=" display:inline; float:left" id="first">
                    <canvas ID="pic1" width="300" height="360" ></canvas>
               </li>
                <li id="second" style="margin-top:0px; display:inline; float:left; position:absolute ">
                    <canvas id="pic2" width="300" height="360"  style="position:absolute" ></canvas>
               </li>
            </ul>
```

Please note that the code might not be correct as it is something I did a while ago, I just want to get an idea of how to do it and if it is possible... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These two links give a pretty good explanation and example of how to rotate with HTML5 canvas

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations

You set the different angles when you rotate (see code example below).
The general gist of it is:

```
1) save the context
2) transform to, usually, the center of the image
3) rotate
4) transform back
5) draw image
6) restore
```

In your case, with two images, you need to transform the origin to the second image before you make the second rotation call. Below is a simplified example rotating one image. Get that sorted and then make the second transform/rotate.

Example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("yourCanvas");
var ctx     = canvas.getContext("2d");
var angle = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){
    angle = angle+1;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

    // first image
    ctx.translate(150,200);
    ctx.rotate( angle*Math.PI/180 );  // rotate 90 degrees
    ctx.translate(-150,-200);

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";  
    ctx.fillRect(100, 150, 100, 100); 
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();
}, 5);​
```

Answer (score 0):

The images are loading asynchronously. This means that that entire function (minus the `onload` handlers for the images happens first. Then when the images are loaded, their handlers are called. This happens in a second pass. By the time this happens, you already rotated and restored the canvas, effectively wiping the rotation out.

The simple fix is to rotate and restore the canvas inside each of the image `onload` handlers.